Deducing Elapsed Time, Connect Time, Latency and Throughput in JMeter
I did a performance script and executed it 5 times for a single user first and got the following results from the Response Graph, View Result Table and Aggregate Graph. I wish to calculate the Elapsed time, Connect Time, Latency and Throughput of this system for this scenario. I realize that I need to increase the user count gracefully and do the load test. For each user count how do I deduce the Connect Time, Latency and Throughput from this output because it's a set of values and not a single value?
Throughput

Latency and Connect Time

Elapsed Time for 5 Runs


If you run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode (which is the recommended way of running the tests anyways) like this:
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx -l /path/to/result.csv

the result.csv file will contain Connect Time, Latency and Elapsed time for each single request so you will be able to "deduce" them (whatever it means)
When it comes to Throughput, according to JMeter Glossary it's

is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
The formula is: Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).

so you will be able to "deduce" it as well (or just open the result.csv file with Aggregate Report listener and it will "deduce" it for you.
P.S. it is also possible to generate HTML Reporting Dashboard
